# I cannot see my partitions appear in Jupyter Notebook. What should I do?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, jupyter

I run Ubuntu 18.04.02 LTS. I have an hard drive of 500GB. I have 4 partitions in it. One for Ubuntu, second for swap, and other two for data. The thing is my other two partitions does not appear in Jupyter Notebook. so I can't access them from notebook and the problem is my all files are situated there and I don't want to move them. So, is there anyway I can do some changes and make them appear in notebook? Something like changing mount point or so. Any help will be appreciated.
[/etc/fstab file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GyQq.png)

Comment: Are these partitions mounted automatically at boot? Please copy and paste the contents of the file `/etc/fstab` in your question. Then format the pasted content as `code` by using the **Format as Code** button { } above the question edit window.

Comment: @user68186 I have attached the screenshot of /etc/fstab file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a symlinks in home to easy access them.

```
mkdir ~/KIRITO
mkdir ~/NARUTO
ln -s /mnt/KIRITO ~/KIRITO
ln -s /mnt/NARUTO ~/NARUTO
```

You will find partitions in home folder